# Displaying images with given URL in a json string on a html page

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on a project where I call a certain API and in response I get back a json string with all the information. I need to find a way using javascript to display this json string into a table format. I got a very basic version of this running. However, the problem I am having is that I cannot find a way to display a image in this block of code.

results.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
 
<head>
    <title>
        How to convert JSON data to a
        html table using JavaScript ?
    </title>

    <h1>Results: </h1>
     
    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
</head>

 
<body style = "text-align:center;" id = "body"> 
     
    
    <h3>Showing resuls for: {{searchQuery}}</h3>
    <p>{{responseText}}</p>

 

    <br><br>
     
    <table align = "center"
            id="table" border="1">
    </table>

    <div id="header"></div>
    
     
    <script>
        var el_up = document.getElementById("GFG_UP");
         

        var list = [];
        list = "{{responseText|escapejs}}";
        //console.log(list);

         var titles = []
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length-8; i++) {
            if(list[i] == 't' && list[i+1] == 'i')
            {
                var title = '';
                for(var j = (i+8); list[j] != ","; j++) {
                    title += list[j];
                }
                i = j;
                console.log(title + ", ")
                titles.push(title)
            }
        }
        console.log(titles)

        var images = []
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length-8; i++) {
            if(list[i] == 'h' && list[i+1] == 't')
            {
                var image = '';
                for(var j = (i); list[j] != ","; j++) {
                    image += list[j];
                }
                i = j;
                console.log(image + ", ");
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = image.slice(0, -1);
                images.push(img);
            }
        }
        console.log(images)

        var restaurants = []
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length-17; i++) {
            if(list[i] == 'r' && list[i+1] == 'e' && list[i+2] == 's')
            {
                var restaurant = '';
                for(var j = (i+17); list[j] != ","; j++) {
                    restaurant += list[j];
                }
                i = j;
                console.log(restaurant + ", ")
                restaurants.push(restaurant)
            }
        }
        console.log(restaurants)

        


        function createTable(tableData) {
            var table = document.createElement('table');
            var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

            tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
                var row = document.createElement('tr');
                console.log(typeof(cellData))
                    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
                    var cell = document.createElement('td');
                    cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
                    row.appendChild(cell);
                
                

                });

                tableBody.appendChild(row);

                })
                
                table.appendChild(tableBody);
            document.body.appendChild(table);
            };

            

var a = [titles, restaurants, images]
console.log(a)
createTable(a);
    




        
    </script>
</body> 
 
</html>
```

The function createTable is the one in question. It displays the text parts correctly. Im not sure how to get it to display images given the URLs of those images in a table.

output HTML file:
[HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Qq1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should show us the API response you are working with here.

Another thing is your **createTable** function expects to get table data. But **onclick** on your button pass there **#table** ID. Not sure if it should be like this.

Also you could run your JS script when all page is loaded:

```
window.onload = () => {
    // Your JS script which should do something after page is loaded.
}
```

Finally it comes to the images. I think that you are not using **img** tag anywhere so your images simply won't be visible in the table. If you would like to see them just create **img** element and put it into **td**.

Few advices (not related with your question):

- stop using console.log so much, place **debugger** statement in your code and debug it like a pro, if you don't know how just look for it in youtube,
- please put your attention to a code style, it is a bit messy, if you have real trouble with it use ESlint to fix it for you.

**EDIT**

About images - if you want to create DOM element for img use code below instead of current one:

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
```

Than you can set **src** and other things like **alt** and so on:

```
img.src = imgUrlString;
```

Comment: Thanks for info. I am new to javascript, so trying to learn all I could. I removed the button as I don't need it anymore. Also when I pass the tabledata(includes array of images) it displays the titles and restaurants but when it comes to the images it displays it as [object HTMLImageElement]

Comment: Also I added a image of the output I am seeing so you can get a better idea of whats going on